# Inno Uninstaller code signing and name

Tags: inno-setup, code-signing

Is there a way to change the name of the auto-generated Inno uninstaller and code-sign it also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sign the uninstaller by setting SignedUninstaller to yes as documented at http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signeduninstaller. 
The uninstaller name cannot be changed.  Because the source for InnoSetup is available, you could change it to change the uninstall file name and recompile it though.